# Is every continious image of a non-compact space is non-compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is every  continuous image of a non-compact space is non-compact?

I was thinking about  constant  function. I think  it will be false.

Am I right?

Comment: If the function is constant, then the image is a singleton, which is definetely compact.

Comment: okss  @ Jose carlos  sir,, that mean  this  is the counter example,,,so statement is false  .Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, the statement is false, for the reason that you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$f(x)=1-x$ , if $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x)=0$, if $x>1$.

Then $f$ is continuous, $[0, \infty)$ is not compact, but $f([0, \infty))=[0,1]$ is compact.